# how to skip integration tests with maven release plugin

Tags: java, maven, integration-testing, maven-release-plugin

I want to skip integration tests while running maven release plugin with command

```
mvn -B -DskipITs release:prepare release:perform
```

It does not seem to work this way. The same option `-DskipITs` works for `mvn install/deploy`. I don't want to use `-Dmaven.test.skip=true` since only integration tests need to be ignored, not unit tests. What is the best way to accomplish this?

**EDIT**: 
`-Darguments=-DskipITs` works for `release:prepare`, but surprising it does **NOT** work for `release:perform`. Tried `-Darguments=-Dmaven.test.skip=true`, does not work either.

Tried to add `<arguments>skipITs</arguments>` for release plugin in the pom, but it would ignore all other `-Darguments` provided in command line. I can't have everything configured in plugin config, since some of the options takes environment variables on the fly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [how to make maven release plugin skip tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28948048/how-to-make-maven-release-plugin-skip-tests), it seems you need both `-DskipITs` and  `-Darguments=-DskipITs`. One is to skip compiling ITs the other is for skipping running ITs.

Comment: Can't seem to edit the post: There's a typo, -DskitITs should be -DskipITs

Answer (score 1):

Use Maven [Profiles](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Build).

Add the following to your pom:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>ItsReleaseTime</id>
        <build>
        <plugins>
        <build> 
            <plugins> 
               <plugin>          
                   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> 
                   <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                   <version>2.20</version>    
                   <configuration>
                        <excludes>    
                              <exclude>**/*IT.java</exclude> 
                        </excludes> 
                   </configuration> 
               </plugin>
            </plugins>       
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

And invoke the command :

```
mvn -B -P ItsReleaseTime release:prepare release:perform
```

Comment: Sorry this is simply wrong, cause maven-surefire-plugin is not responsible for running integration tests...and this naming schema is by default not used by maven-surefire-plugin. This is the naming schema from the maven-failsafe-plugin...

Answer (score -1):

You can add some setting in your `pm.xml` file.

```
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.12.4</version>
      <configuration>
         <skipTests>true</skipTests>
      </configuration>
   </plugin>
```

Comment: I tried to avoid this, because most of the time tests will run. Only when it is being deployed in CICD pipeline. Plus wouldn't this skip unit tests as well?

Comment: The question was about skipping integration tests; not all tests